# Is there a word for when the situation returns to normal after chaos?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Imagine a situation where the Internet connection at your office of 1000 people goes down. You, as the IT person, are responsible for fixing it. You immediately turn on the red lights and alarms.

Two minutes later, the Internet is back and all is back to normal and it wasn't your fault.

In Hebrew, you might say, "Hazlash!" You'd mean that the crisis is over and that your alarms can be ignored.

Is there a word in English comparable to "hazlash?"

Comment: Notice that Hazlash is, indeed, an abbreviation and not a single word. But it is rather useful one. It doesn't directly mean "all clear" as all clear necessarily goes in a positive direction while Hazlash could also go back to the panic situation. E.g. there's a problem which causes chaos or panic, someone reckoned to have found the problem and relaxes everyone only to realise that the problem wasn't actually solved. I'd say this case would also justify using Hazlash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “All clear”

This is the phrase one might employ in Britain, especially if one is of the older generation. It was the term for the siren used in World War II after an air raid (although it predates this) and has featured in many movies and TV dramas portraying that period. It became a noun phrase “the all clear”, as this [BBC page](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p03txxr7) documents.

See also the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_clear).

Comment: Interestingly, I learned this word "hazlash" from my friend who says it is in heavy use in the Israeli military. So, the military background of both would be a nice mirror.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'crisis averted', however it is not a one word. Urban dictionary suggests: Pheww https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pheww ;)

Comment: The connotation I have for "crisis averted" is that the bad thing never did happen. I think "hazlash" is more a sense of the hazard has passed and we are OK now but it was a real hazard at some point. That's a very fine point though. This is definitely a possible match.